# Bash: create multiple arrays from loop output

Tags: arrays, bash, performance, loops, variables

I have a 'working' result. I want to make it  more efficient, refine the process.
Follow me, below:

I am running the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
varPATH+=($(find /usr/share/doc/nano/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -readable))
for i in ${varPATH[@]} ; do
        md5sum $i | sed 's/\.\///g'
done
```

... output ...

```
3d4b12cf0073d9aeebbf29e661fd5da5  AUTHORS
bf9b099648cb1200eb2fa4434c3c4547  BUGS.gz
c7dcba1d8e5a6e0a88ced9929b2630ae  changelog.Debian.gz
d2b7963b6bcf44a590001e7c5b0ef8a8  changelog.gz
e70e5c9b500efd2a540c999dceb8f06c  copyright
aa867595b2958564c4b32ed6ea591cd7  faq.html
99724dc74c18b19a5433ac3624258e56  NEWS.gz
```

I want the md5sum to be added to array1 and the filename to be added to array2

If I loop through a sequence for both arrays, array1[22] and array2[22] match up accordingly but also without having to MD5 the file more than one time.

I have created a new script that can achieve this result, but I'm hoping to get critique or a better way to achieve the same result. This method seems "heavy" or requiring more process than needed.

script:

```
#!/bin/bash
varPATH+=($(find /usr/share/doc/nano/ -maxdepth 1 -type f))
unset ar1; unset ar2; unset ar3; unset ar4; unset ar5
bentest ()      {
                for i in ${varPATH[@]} ; do
                        md5sum $i | sed 's/\.\///g'
                done
                }
ar1+=($(bentest))
count1=0
count2=1
while [ $count1 -lt ${#ar1[@]} ]; do
        ar2+=($(echo ${ar1[$count1]}))
        ar4+=($count1)
        let count1+=2
done

while [ $count2 -lt ${#ar1[@]} ]; do
        ar3+=($(echo ${ar1[$count2]}))
        ar5+=($count2)
        let count2+=2
done

count3=0
count4=0
count5=0
while [ $count3 -lt ${#ar1[@]} ]; do
        echo "ar1[$count3] = ${ar1[$count3]}"
        let count3+=1
done
while [ $count4 -lt ${#ar2[@]} ]; do
        echo "ar2[$count4] = ${ar2[$count4]}"
        let count4+=1
done
while [ $count5 -lt ${#ar3[@]} ]; do
        echo "ar3[$count5] = ${ar3[$count5]}"
        let count5+=1
done
```

... output that shows this method IS sane ...

```
ar1[0] = aa867595b2958564c4b32ed6ea591cd7
ar1[1] = /usr/share/doc/nano/faq.html
ar1[2] = e70e5c9b500efd2a540c999dceb8f06c
ar1[3] = /usr/share/doc/nano/copyright
ar1[4] = d2b7963b6bcf44a590001e7c5b0ef8a8
ar1[5] = /usr/share/doc/nano/changelog.gz
ar1[6] = 3d4b12cf0073d9aeebbf29e661fd5da5
ar1[7] = /usr/share/doc/nano/AUTHORS
ar1[8] = 9319db0df664b9fcfe6937b78666c607
ar1[9] = /usr/share/doc/nano/UPGRADE.gz
ar1[10] = 99724dc74c18b19a5433ac3624258e56
ar1[11] = /usr/share/doc/nano/NEWS.gz
ar1[12] = bf9b099648cb1200eb2fa4434c3c4547
ar1[13] = /usr/share/doc/nano/BUGS.gz
ar1[14] = 54cdb409a70b74d1a8b41a731e0d9ef5
ar1[15] = /usr/share/doc/nano/THANKS
ar1[16] = c7dcba1d8e5a6e0a88ced9929b2630ae
ar1[17] = /usr/share/doc/nano/changelog.Debian.gz
ar1[18] = 2864bac6c4e3e9264a8a68509e511e81
ar1[19] = /usr/share/doc/nano/TODO.gz
ar1[20] = a4ee8fd431a8db6cc84a7fb6c29931b9
ar1[21] = /usr/share/doc/nano/README
ar2[0] = aa867595b2958564c4b32ed6ea591cd7
ar2[1] = e70e5c9b500efd2a540c999dceb8f06c
ar2[2] = d2b7963b6bcf44a590001e7c5b0ef8a8
ar2[3] = 3d4b12cf0073d9aeebbf29e661fd5da5
ar2[4] = 9319db0df664b9fcfe6937b78666c607
ar2[5] = 99724dc74c18b19a5433ac3624258e56
ar2[6] = bf9b099648cb1200eb2fa4434c3c4547
ar2[7] = 54cdb409a70b74d1a8b41a731e0d9ef5
ar2[8] = c7dcba1d8e5a6e0a88ced9929b2630ae
ar2[9] = 2864bac6c4e3e9264a8a68509e511e81
ar2[10] = a4ee8fd431a8db6cc84a7fb6c29931b9
ar3[0] = /usr/share/doc/nano/faq.html
ar3[1] = /usr/share/doc/nano/copyright
ar3[2] = /usr/share/doc/nano/changelog.gz
ar3[3] = /usr/share/doc/nano/AUTHORS
ar3[4] = /usr/share/doc/nano/UPGRADE.gz
ar3[5] = /usr/share/doc/nano/NEWS.gz
ar3[6] = /usr/share/doc/nano/BUGS.gz
ar3[7] = /usr/share/doc/nano/THANKS
ar3[8] = /usr/share/doc/nano/changelog.Debian.gz
ar3[9] = /usr/share/doc/nano/TODO.gz
ar3[10] = /usr/share/doc/nano/README
```

Comment: What's the end effect that you'd like to have?

Comment: I'm building a script that I can run against a directory to automatically generate apache file descriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method which worked for me which loops over the output from your original script which creates the hash-codes with the file-names:-

```
#!/bin/bash

md5sumArray=()
nameArray=()
while read -r md5sum name;
do
    md5sumArray+=("$md5sum")
    nameArray+=("$name")
done < <(find /usr/share/doc/nano/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c 'file={}; md5sum $file | sed "s/\.\///g"' \;)
```

With this you no longer need another script to populate the array containing the `md5sum`.

You can later test your arrays by printing them as below:-

```
for element in "${md5sumArray[@]}"
do
    echo "$element"
done

for element in "${nameArray[@]}"
do
    echo "$element"
done
```

Hope the script is self-explanatory.

Comment: this is good, but the top portion of code in your answer asks for the code from the script I've initially created. 
In my code below:
    `for i in ${varPATH[@]} ; do
        md5sum $i | sed 's/\.\///g'; 
    done`
I'd like to see this above command fed into two arrays without having to create a third array

Comment: @Benjamin: Refer my updated answer and provide your suggestions on the same.

Comment: this is great, thanks. 
`done < <(find /usr/share/doc/nano/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c 'file={}; md5sum $file | sed "s/\.\///g"' \;)`
I haven't used bash like this a lot, I'll have to practice this a lot more, thanks